# Python str formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

I am using Python 3.8.10.

```
result = "<svg id='{id}' class='{class}' height='{height}{unit}' width='{width}{unit}'>".format(id=image_id, class=html_class, height=str(height), unit=unit_of_measure)
```

I get this error message:

```
 File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/images_outer/images_project/images/templatetags/images.py", line 131
    result = "<svg id='{id}' class='{class}' height='{height}{unit}' width='{width}{unit}'>".format(id=image_id, class=html_class, height=str(height), unit=str(unit_of_measure))
                                                                                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
python-BaseException

Process finished with exit code 130 (interrupted by signal 2: SIGINT)
```

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: ```class``` is a keyword for defining a class

Comment: In similar situations, `class_` is the recommended variable name (stackoverflow.com/a/6504209/5378816)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`class` is a builtin keyword in python, so cannot be used in this context. Instead of `str.format()` use the alternative "f-string" syntax for formatting strings, e.g.:

```
result = f"<svg id='{image_id}' class='{html_class}' height='{height}{unit_of_measure}' width='{width}{unit_of_measure}'>"
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using python 3.x you can use f strings

```
result = f"<svg id='{id}' class='{class}' height='{height}{unit}' width='{width}{unit}'>"
```

Comment: The above string will not give what OP wants. You are substituting ```class``` and ```id``` which are in built in python

Comment: i just give an example. Please change the variable names